# iOS - App Store view app purchase history

Tags: ios-appstore

I didn’t pay attention in which iOS version it happened but as you know, Apple redesigned their App Store.

However there’s something I can’t find anymore with this version of App Store: The whole list of purchased apps associated with the iCloud account signed in.

In the previous App Store you could go to `App Store app → Updates` and, on top of the list, there was an item named Purchased, that, when clicked, would show a list of purchased apps in a descending chronological order.

Where can we find that list now that Apple redesigned the App Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple [introduced](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09192017c) the first major App Store re-design with iOS 11.

In the re-designed App Store app, you can easily find the list of app purchases *linked* to the Apple ID currently logged into iTunes & App Store, by tapping on the **Account profile picture** visible towards top right on all of **Today**, **Games**, **Apps** and **Updates** tabs.

To view the list of purchased apps:

1. Open App Store App. Tap on the Account profile picture shown towards top right, from any one of the tabs.
2. A new screen animates from the bottom. Tap on Purchased.
3. Voila! All the linked apps are listed.
4. Above steps are similar on both iPhone and iPad

#### iPhone:

[image] [image] [image]

#### iPad:

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Important Note**: The question contains a statement:

> However there’s something I can’t find anymore with this version of App Store: The whole list of purchased apps associated with the iCloud account signed in.

Do note, that different Apples ID's can be used to sign into **iCloud** and **iTunes & App Store** on a **single** iOS device at the **same time**. The apps listed under **Purchased** section in the App Store app are linked to the Apple ID signed into **iTunes & App Store** under Setting app and **not** the **iCloud** Apple ID. Apple ID for iCloud and iTunes & App Store can be managed separately.

[image]

Comment: I wasn’t aware de profile photo is clickable. Thanks!